# QGIS Convert Shapefile to MSSQL as geography type

Tags: qgis, geometry, export, sql-server, geography

I am using QGIS 3.16 and SQL Server 2019.

I have a shapefile loaded into the project.  I have been able to successfully convert the Shapefile to a spatial dataset in SQL Server.  My method for doing this is to just drag and drop the layer into the chosen SQL Server schema, works like a charm.

The problem is that it appears in the database as Geometry instead of Geography.  I really need it to be of Geography type for the subsequent calculations that I need to do.  I thought it might be related to my project or layer CRS so I set both of those to a CRS that I knew was compatible with SQL Servers list of reference systems from sys.spatial_reference_systems, however trying that it seems nothing I do can make it appear as geography type in the table after the export.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Try using ogr2ogr, see: https://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/ he/she are using the flag `-lco "GEOM_TYPE=geography"`. I have no SQL server to try it on

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I found out that we had a license of FME that would work before I had a chance to try your solution.